# How to make the input between two numbers

Tags: python

I want to force the users input to be between two numbers e.g. 5-15 and if it isn't between or equal too these numbers say please enter a number between these two and request another input.

I already have an input that forces you to enter an interger.

```
while True:

 try:
    # asking for race length
    race_length = int(input("Choose the Length You Would Like You Race To Be (Between 5 and 15)"))
except ValueError:
    print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.")
    #if an interger isn't entered do loop above to avoid and error
    continue
else:
    #race length succesfully found
    #finished the loop
    break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use if-else to check if the value is within the required range or not if yes then assign it to the **race_length**

if not ask user to enter again.

```
if(x>5 and x<15):
   race_length  = x
else:
   input('Choose the Length You Would Like You Race To Be (Between 5 and 15)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it raise an error using `assert <bool>` and handle `AssertionError`
See the following code,

```
while True:
    try:
        race_length = int(input("Choose the Length You Would Like You Race To Be (Between 5 and 15) : "))
        assert 5 < race_length < 15
    except ValueError:
        print("Sorry, I didn't understand that.")
    except AssertionError:
        print("Please Enter a number between 5 and 15")
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Note that this only works in debug mode (if `__debug__` is `True`)